# locating jar file in $PATH environment variable for java -jar command

Tags: java

I want to run a simple executable jar like this:

```
java -jar /path/to/my/jar/myjar.jar
```

However, i have to put that absolute path every time I want to run it. Is there a way to tell the OS to look for the jar in `$PATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

You can also copy your jar file to /usr/bin folder, then it will work with just `$ myjar.jar`

Make sure your jar file has the executable bit (`chmod +x myjar.jar`) and copy it to /usr/bin (`sudo cp myjar.jar /usr/bin/myjar.jar`)

Comment: it doesn't work. When i tried it, it shows an error: invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error

Comment: What Linux distro are you using? If it's Ubuntu, before you copy it to /usr/bin, try right-clicking on your jar file and open the Properties dialog. Click on the Open With tab and select something in the lines of Sun Java Runtime. Then try to run the jar by double-clicking on it in Nautilus. If that works, it will work from command line as well when you copy it again.

Comment: i am using fedora, but i tried to do the same, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd use the classpath; append your directory to it and `java -jar myjar.jar` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CLASSPATH](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html) environment variable instead

Comment: can you show an example? i tried to put the path in CLASSPATH, i got this error: Unable to access jarfile myjar.jar

Comment: try: java `your.Class` where is the one that has the main method in that class. Since your .jar is already in the CLASSPATH, everything should run. On the other hand, quite frankly, what I do is to create .sh file in my $HOME/bin with the content : `java -jar /full/path/to/my/File.jar` but I'm not sure if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The -jar directive overrides the classpath, using whatever is defined in the jar file itself. The best way to do what you need is to use a tool such as ant, a script, or copy it to somewhere where the OS can find it (as Nejc Saje suggested).